# AWS SNS using PHP SDK V3

Tags: php, notification, aws, sdk, amazon

I am currently using php to send a notification email to myself to get comfortable with it for being able to do it for someone I work for. I am trying to set up a form and when the form is submitted from a website it should send a notification to my email to what was inputted to the form.

I understand the code and how to use it but I am having trouble with how to send the notification of the form from the website using the submit button. How would I be able to map the button so it send a message to AWS to send the notification.

Answer (score 0):

The button resides on the client in HTML. When the button is pressed, you need to execute JavaScript to call (POST to) your web server.

Client side Ajax code:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/mypage.php",
        data: { first_name: "Howard", last_name: "Johnson" }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert("Data Sent: " + msg);
    });
});
```

Server side in PHP: /mypage.php:

```
<?php
echo "Hello " . $_POST["first_name"];
// Add your real code here that calls SNS
?>
```